# BigQuery insert job

Tags: python, insert, google-bigquery

I want to create an insert job function in Python similar to the following streaming function:

```
def stream_data(dataset_name, table_name, data):
   bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
   dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)
   table = dataset.table(table_name)

   # Reload the table to get the schema.
   table.reload()
   rows = data
   errors = table.insert_data(rows)
   if not errors:
      print('Loaded 1 row into {}:{}'.format(dataset_name, table_name))
   else:
      print('Errors:')
      print(errors)
```

The data argument is a list containing rows (rows are lists). I would like to recreate this function but then with a 'regular' insert/load job... the official documentation did not really help me in this process.